Getting the Last Document Reference for Pagination when using valueChanges()
I'm using valueChanges() in AngularFire to subscribe to Firestore data and need to get the last document reference for pagination.
I was previously using onSnapshot with
.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
this.lastV = qSnapshot.docs[qSnapshot.docs.length - 1]
}

But this doesn't work with valueChanges(). How can I achieve this, I want to retrieve a reference to the last document and pass it in startAfter(lastV).
.valueChanges().subscribe(qItems => {
        if (Array.isArray(qItems) && qItems.length > 0) {
          const lastDoc = qItems[qItems.length - 1];
          this.lastV = this.firestore.doc(`${this.getPath()}/${lastDoc.uuid}`);


The only way I can think of is to add some timestamp like a date and then query accordingly, for example:
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
   this.items = afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(1));
   this.items.valueChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a['payload'].doc.data() as Item;
            return {...data };
        });
      }

Use orderBy to be able to get the last document and limit to limit it to the number of documents that you want
